# Mocking third-party service Go gives error: index out of range [-1]

Tags: go, mocking

So I'm using a package called [Gocron](https://github.com/go-co-op/gocron). The code application code itself works perfectly via interfaces, however the issue comes once I try to mock out the package in my tests.

Here is my test file along with the mock that I created for the Gocron package:

```
type mockGoCron struct{}

func (mSh *mockGoCron) StartBlocking() {
    fmt.Println("hey")
}

func (mSh *mockGoCron) Every(interface{}) *gocron.Scheduler {
    return gocron.NewScheduler(time.UTC)
}

func (mSh *mockGoCron) Seconds() *gocron.Scheduler {
    return &gocron.Scheduler{}
}

func (mSh *mockGoCron) Minutes() *gocron.Scheduler {
    return &gocron.Scheduler{}
}

func NewMockGoCron() *mockGoCron {
    return &mockGoCron{}
}

var (
    sh scheduler.Scheduler = scheduler.Scheduler{
        Sched:   NewMockGoCron(),
        AllJobs: scheduler.AllJobs{},
    }
    job scheduler.Job = scheduler.Job{
        Name:              "testJob",
        TimeInterval:      "1",
        TimeUnit:          "seconds",
        ActionTriggerName: "testAction",
    }
)

var _ = Describe("Scheduler", func() {
    Describe("Initializing jobs", func() {
        Context("When initializing a job", func() {
            It("Should return true", func() {
                Expect(sh.InitJob(job)).To(Equal(true))
                sh.InitJob(job)
            })
        })
    })
})
```

Here is the application code:

```
//main.go
func main() {
    ...
    sh := scheduler.NewScheduler()
    sh.InitScheduler()
}

// scheduler.go
type SchedulerInterface interface {
    StartBlocking()
    Every(interface{}) *gocron.Scheduler
    Seconds() *gocron.Scheduler
    Minutes() *gocron.Scheduler
}

type Scheduler struct {
    Sched   SchedulerInterface
    AllJobs AllJobs
}

type ScheduleHandler interface {
    InitScheduler(*gocron.Scheduler, AllJobs) bool
    InitJob(*gocron.Scheduler, Job) bool
}

func NewScheduler() *Scheduler {
    goC := gocron.NewScheduler(time.UTC)
    return &Scheduler{
        Sched:   goC,
        AllJobs: AllJobs{},
    }
}

func (sh *Scheduler) InitJob(job Job) bool {
    timeInterval, _ := strconv.Atoi(job.TimeInterval)

    switch job.TimeUnit {
    case "seconds":
        sh.Sched.Every(timeInterval).Seconds().Do(doSomeFunc)
        return true
    case "minutes":
        sh.Sched.Every(timeInterval).Minutes().Do(doSomeFunc)
        return true
    }

    return false
}

// Initialize Scheduler
func (sh *Scheduler) InitScheduler() {
    sh.AllJobs.ParseJobs("./jobs.json")

    for k, v := range sh.AllJobs.Jobs {
        sh.InitJob(v)
    }

    sh.Sched.StartBlocking()
}
```

Here is the error:

```
Test Panicked
      runtime error: index out of range [-1]
      /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:88

      Full Stack Trace
      github.com/go-co-op/gocron.(*Scheduler).getCurrentJob(...)
        /Users/garrettlove/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-co-op/gocron@v1.1.0/scheduler.go:743
      github.com/go-co-op/gocron.(*Scheduler).setUnit(0xc000140240, 0x1)
        /Users/garrettlove/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-co-op/gocron@v1.1.0/scheduler.go:604 +0x17a
      github.com/go-co-op/gocron.(*Scheduler).Seconds(...)
        /Users/garrettlove/go/pkg/mod/github.com/go-co-op/gocron@v1.1.0/scheduler.go:629
      bitbucket.org/garrettlove/dfd-api/internal/scheduler.(*Scheduler).InitJob(0x16a1ca0, 0x13c1508, 0x7, 0x13bd99e, 0x1, 0x13c13b8, 0x7, 0x13c363e, 0xa, 0x16c3e20)
        /Users/garrettlove/go/src/bitbucket.org/garrettlove8/dfd-api/rules-processor/internal/scheduler/scheduler.go:47 +0x165
      bitbucket.org/garrettlove/dfd-api/internal/scheduler_test.glob..func1.1.1.1()
        /Users/garrettlove/go/src/bitbucket.org/garrettlove8/dfd-api/rules-processor/internal/scheduler/scheduler_test.go:183 +0x65
      github.com/onsi/ginkgo/internal/leafnodes.(*runner).runSync(0xc0000268a0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        /Users/garrettlove/go/pkg/mod/github.com/onsi/ginkgo@v1.16.0/internal/leafnodes/runner.go:113 +0xa3
      github.com/onsi/ginkgo/internal/leafnodes.(*runner).run(0xc0000268a0, 0x104310a, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        /Users/garrettlove/go/pkg/mod/github.com/onsi/ginkgo@v1.16.0/internal/leafnodes/runner.go:64 +0xd7
      github.com/onsi/ginkgo/internal/leafnodes.(*ItNode).Run(0xc00000eaa0, 0x1432340, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
        /Users/garrettlove/go/pkg/mod/github.com/onsi/ginkgo@v1.16.0/internal/leafnodes/it_node.go:26 +0x67
      github.com/onsi/ginkgo/internal/spec.(*Spec).runSample(0xc0001d2000, 0x0, 0x1432340, 0xc000072b40)
        /Users/garrettlove/go/pkg/mod/github.com/onsi/ginkgo@v1.16.0/internal/spec/spec.go:215 +0x691
      github.com/onsi/ginkgo/internal/spec.(*Spec).Run(0xc0001d2000, 0x1432340, 0xc000072b40)
        /Users/garrettlove/go/pkg/mod/github.com/onsi/ginkgo@v1.16.0/internal/spec/spec.go:138 +0xf2
      github.com/onsi/ginkgo/internal/specrunner.(*SpecRunner).runSpec(0xc0001466e0, 0xc0001d2000, 0x0)
        /Users/garrettlove/go/pkg/mod/github.com/onsi/ginkgo@v1.16.0/internal/specrunner/spec_runner.go:200 +0x111
      github.com/onsi/ginkgo/internal/specrunner.(*SpecRunner).runSpecs(0xc0001466e0, 0x1)
        /Users/garrettlove/go/pkg/mod/github.com/onsi/ginkgo@v1.16.0/internal/specrunner/spec_runner.go:170 +0x127
      github.com/onsi/ginkgo/internal/specrunner.(*SpecRunner).Run(0xc0001466e0, 0xc000012d60)
        /Users/garrettlove/go/pkg/mod/github.com/onsi/ginkgo@v1.16.0/internal/specrunner/spec_runner.go:66 +0x117
      github.com/onsi/ginkgo/internal/suite.(*Suite).Run(0xc000127490, 0x1d7e210, 0xc000001b00, 0x13c5f9c, 0xf, 0xc000061340, 0x1, 0x1, 0x1439ac0, 0xc000072b40, ...)
        /Users/garrettlove/go/pkg/mod/github.com/onsi/ginkgo@v1.16.0/internal/suite/suite.go:79 +0x586
      github.com/onsi/ginkgo.runSpecsWithCustomReporters(0x1432820, 0xc000001b00, 0x13c5f9c, 0xf, 0xc00004a728, 0x1, 0x1, 0xc00004a738)
        /Users/garrettlove/go/pkg/mod/github.com/onsi/ginkgo@v1.16.0/ginkgo_dsl.go:238 +0x238
      github.com/onsi/ginkgo.RunSpecs(0x1432820, 0xc000001b00, 0x13c5f9c, 0xf, 0x6c49ac23d89c6)
        /Users/garrettlove/go/pkg/mod/github.com/onsi/ginkgo@v1.16.0/ginkgo_dsl.go:213 +0xa7
      bitbucket.org/garrettlove/dfd-api/internal/scheduler_test.TestJobs(0xc000001b00)
        /Users/garrettlove/go/src/bitbucket.org/garrettlove8/dfd-api/rules-processor/internal/scheduler/scheduler_suite_test.go:12 +0x98
      testing.tRunner(0xc000001b00, 0x13e16b8)
        /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1123 +0xef
      created by testing.(*T).Run
        /usr/local/go/src/testing/testing.go:1168 +0x2b3
```

What am I missing here? Am I mocking something out incorrectly? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Scheduler's `Every()` [appends an internal `jobs` array](https://github.com/go-co-op/gocron/blob/master/scheduler.go#L390).

In your mock implementation, `Every()` just returns a Scheduler where `Every` was never called. In the subsequent call to `Seconds()`, because this internal array was never filled with at least one element, `getCurrentJob` panics.

If you're providing a `SchedulerInterface` to "abstract" gocron, it's a bit odd that its methods return `*gocron.Scheduler`. In some sense, it's still causing the code to hardly depend on gocron. There are two options IMO:

1. Create a wrapper around gocron's Scheduler: this allows more control over the return types and such. Plus, your wrapper can implement a custom interface, which you can mock in the test.
2. (least effort) Just use gocron in itself. Once the test is finished, you can simply call `Stop()` to the scheduler.